# Optimize memory usage by cocos2d App : How to manage large package in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have the problem with download a large package content in cocos2d when i bought a category.

It's 100 MB. I must be finish download to use this category.

It includes:  Spritesheet, background, sound object. Each category has 20 objects.

Does anyone suggest for me an idea ? I don't want that the customer is taking up so much of their time.

Comment: Do you mean: you have an in-app purchase item the user can buy, and if he did, the package he will have to download is 100 MB? Is that package already compressed (ZIP, GZ, ..)? Any reason not to include the package with the app and just unlock it? If piracy is the only reason not to do that, reconsider: you're designing for your users, not to defend against pirates.

Comment: Yes. The file which the users needs to download is 100Mb. My package is compressed zip. I afraid, the user could not wait until it comleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iPhone or Mac?

Check This: [Cocos2d memory optimisation](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/)

Here is some of my suggestions that we did in one of our cocos2d iPhone game.

- Used Jpeg2000 image formate for background image : bit increased loading time..but reduced app size.
- Use Audio with bitrate 128 Kbps
- Use Texture Packer to create spriteSheet and make sure you set NPOT option..by default its POT. See image for more information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir. It's useful for me

Comment: Welcome Sir..Happy coding :)